# 100% width of collectionView with CGSize in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I am trying to get 100% of the width of my `collectionView` with Swift 3 but I am confused. The method I am trying does not work. So far I have:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 25)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to accomplish this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 25)
}
```

`collectionView.frame.size.width` will get the width of the `collectionView`.

**Note**: The the parameters passed in are points, *not* percentages. So what you are returning is 100 points x 25 points. Thanks @Randy for the reminder!

Comment: Yes, it's important to point out the fact that `CGSize(width: 100, height: 25)` returns a size of 100 points * 25 points. It doesn't take percentages as arguments, but points.

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed.

Comment: _But I want Un-sung Hero!_ Well I am one the one to decide. @shallowThought it is possible he read my bio: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5236226/caleb-kleveter?tab=profile

Comment: @CalebKleveter Haha. Sorry.

Comment: @shallowThought Don't feel bad. It doesn't effect more score that much: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395337/how-unsung-am-i

Answer (score 2):

I have a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass that I use.  Note that you probably want to take into account insets, etc.

```
class AutoSizingCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 0
  @IBInspectable var spacing: CGFloat = 0

  override func prepareLayout() {
    let containerBounds = (self.collectionView?.window != nil) ? self.collectionView?.bounds : UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    var size = self.itemSize
    size.width = CGRectGetWidth(containerBounds!)
    size.width -= (self.sectionInset.left + self.sectionInset.right)
    size.height = height
    self.itemSize = size

    self.minimumLineSpacing = spacing

    super.prepareLayout()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in **Swift 4**:

```
var collectionWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    collectionWidth -= collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right
}
```

The new iPhone nudge needs the safe area to be checked